# Java: How to export an openstreetmap area to an image file?

Tags: java, api, export, openstreetmap

I am searching now for a longer time without any success. Currently I am searching for a solution in Java for exporting or printing an open street map area based on a lat and long.

Is there any Java API / Framework which I can use to convert an area of an OSM map to a PNG, PDF, JPEG or whatever, so that I am able to print it afterwards?

Openstreetmaps is for example offering an export service, which fits to my needs, but I would like to be more flexible.

http://parent.tile.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=11.xxxxxx,48.xxxxxx,11.xxxxxx,48.xxxxxx&scale=1439&format=png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After longer research I found a great API, which seems to be reliable :-)

http://ojw.dev.openstreetmap.org/StaticMap/

This API has a lot of great configuration possibilities ...

Comment: Due to excessive usage, this API is no longer available, see [link](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/26293/error-on-image-stream-using-ojwdevopenstreetmaporg/26297)

Answer (score 1):

The open street map tiles are already 256 x 256 .png images.  Here's one tile from zoom level 8, folder 61, image 103

[image: Shreveport, Louisiana, USA]

In Java, you assemble them to make a map, usually with a BufferedImage.  You can save this BufferedImage as a JPEG or a PNG file.

Comment: I am already aware of that, but I am searching for a library what is doing that for me.

Comment: You didn't mention tiles in your question, so how was I supposed to know?  I suspect it would be quicker to just write the code yourself.

Comment: hoped that I didn't have to do it :) so I am waiting for more responses. Thanks anyway!